# Group JSON data depending on the first 3 columns and sum the number of the 4th column in HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a JSON file and I want to create multiple HTML tables depending on a combination of values in the JSON objects.

Let's have a look at a sample of a JSON to give a better explanation:

```
var data = {"headers":["plat","chan","cat","num"],"rows":[["plat1","chan1","cat1",1],
["plat1","chan1","cat1",2],["plat2","chan1","cat2",5]]};
```

In the example above, we have 2 rows with the same values in the first three columns. I want to generate an HTML table with one row (because the values are the same) but the fourth column must have the SUM.

So, the HTML table must be like:
*plat1, chan1, cat1, **3***
*plat2, chan1, cat2, **5***

The snippet below was based on an initial script and the help of a fellow stackoverflow user :)

```js
var data = {"headers":["plat","chan","group","cat","num"],"rows":[["plat1","chan1","bbb","cat1",222],
["plat1","chan1","bbb","cat1",333],
["plat1","chan1","bbb","cat2",850]]};

// transform the data to get a clear connection between the
// heading and the corresponding data
const transformedData = data.rows.map((row) => {
 const emptyRowDataObject = {};
 return row.reduce((dataObjSoFar, rowData, rowDataIndex) => {
   // for each of the values in the row, add a property
    // with the name of the corresponding header
    const correspondingHeader = data.headers[rowDataIndex];
   dataObjSoFar[correspondingHeader] = rowData;
    return dataObjSoFar;
  }, emptyRowDataObject);
});

const headersOfInterest = ['plat','chan','cat','num'];
printTable(headersOfInterest, transformedData);


function printTable(headers, rowDataWithHeaders) {
 let tableHeader = createTableHeaders(headers);
  let tableRows = rowDataWithHeaders.map(row => createTableRow(headers, row));
  let table = `<table>${ tableHeader }<tbody>${ tableRows }</tbody></table>`;
  $("#one").html(table);
}

function createTableHeaders(headers) {
 let headersHTML = '<thead><tr>';
 headers.forEach(header => {
   headersHTML += `<th>${ header }</th>`;
  });
  headersHTML += '</tr></thead>';
  return headersHTML;
}

function createTableRow(headers, dataRow) {
 let tr = '<tr>';
  // go through all the headers we are interested in
  // and get the corresponding value from this data row
  headers.forEach(header => {
   tr += `<td>${ dataRow[header] }</td>`;
  });
  tr += '</tr>';
  return tr;
}

function getSumOfValuesInColumn(headerName, rowDataWithHeaders) {
 // this could be done with Array.reduce as well
  let sum = 0;
 for(let i = 0; i < rowDataWithHeaders.length; i++) {
   sum += rowDataWithHeaders[i][headerName]
  }
  return sum;
}

function printSummationTable(headersToSum, dataRows) {
 const tableHeader = createTableHeaders(headersToSum);
  const sumData = {};
  headersToSum.forEach(header => {
   sumData[header] = getSumOfValuesInColumn(header, dataRows);
  });
  // treat sumData as a single table row
  const tableRows = createTableRow(headersToSum, sumData);
  let table = `<table>${ tableHeader }<tbody>${ tableRows }</tbody></table>`;
  $("#two").html(table);
}

const headersToSum = ['plat','chan','cat','num'];
printSummationTable(headersToSum, transformedData);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');

body { 
    margin: 0;
    color:#fff;
    font-family: Roboto; }
.row {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 241px; 
    background-color:#454545;
}
.row > .col-lg-6 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.container {
  /*display: flex;*/
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container > div {
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px;
  flex: 0 0 calc(100% - 20px);
  text-align: left;
}

/*img {
    padding-left: 7%;
    max-height:55px;
    width:auto;
}*/
td{
  padding: 2px 2px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 6px 0;
  border: none;
}
table{
  width: 100%;
  background-color:#454545;
  font-weight:500;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing:0.3em 1.1em;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
}
tr{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-transform:capitalize;
}
tr:nth-child(1) {
    color: #CCC;
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
 
#one,#two,#three,#four{
    padding-top:2%;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h4 style="color:#000;">Table before summing the number for the rows that have the same value in the first three columns</h4>
<div id="one"></div>
<h4 style="color:#000;">Table where we can see the SUM but for all the rows. The first three columns are a concatenation of the values which should not happen.</h4>
<div id="two"></div>
<h4 style="color:#000;">Table that I want to get (static)</h4>
<div><table> <thead> <tr> <th>plat</th> <th>chan</th> <th>cat</th> <th>num</th> </tr></thead> <tbody> <tr> <td>plat1</td><td>chan1</td><td>cat1</td><td>555</td></tr><tr> <td>plat1</td><td>chan1</td><td>cat2</td><td>850</td></tr></tbody></table></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created the following answer, I hope it meets your needs.

```js
var data = {
  "headers":["plat","chan","group","cat","num"],
  "rows":[  
    ["plat1","chan1","bbb","cat1",222],
    ["plat1","chan1","bbb","cat1",333],
    ["plat1","chan1","bbb","cat2",850]
  ]
};


function transformData(rows) {
  const 
    rowMap = new Map(),
    result = [];
    
  // Iterate over the rows.
  rows.forEach(row => {
    const
      // Create a key, it is the first 4 elements joined together.
      key = row.slice(0,4).join();
      
    // Check if the Map has the generated key...
    if (rowMap.has(key)) {
      // The map has the key, we need to add up the values
      const
        // Get the value for the current key.
        storedRow = rowMap.get(key);
        // Add the value of the current row to the row in the map.
        storedRow[4] += row[4];
    } else {
      // The key doens't exist yet, add the row to the map.
      rowMap.set(key, row);
    }
  });
  
  // Iterate over all the entries in the map and push each value with the
  // summed up value into the array.
  rowMap.forEach(value => {
    result.push(value);
  });
    
  // Return the array.
  return result;   
}

// Creates cells for all items in the row array. When no cell type is set
// the method will create td elements.
function getCells(row, element = 'td') {
  // Reduce the array to a single string.
  return row.reduce((result, cell) => {
    result += `<${element}>${cell}</${element}>`;
    
    return result;
  }, '');
}

// Creates tr elements for each item in the rows array, each tr element
// will be filled with td elements.
function getBody(rows) {
  // Reduce the array to a single string.
  return rows.reduce((result, row) => {
    result += `<tr>${getCells(row)}</tr>`
    
    return result;
  }, '');
}

// Create the HTML table.
function createTable(tableData) {
  let
    tableHTML = '';
    
  tableHTML = `<table>
    <thead><tr>${getCells(tableData.headers, 'th')}</tr></thead>
    <tbody>${getBody(tableData.rows)}</tbody>
  </table>`;
  
  return tableHTML;
}


data.rows = transformData(data.rows);
const
  generateHTML = createTable(data);
$("#two").html(generateHTML);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');

body { 
    margin: 0;
    color:#fff;
    font-family: Roboto; }
.row {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 241px; 
    background-color:#454545;
}
.row > .col-lg-6 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.container {
  /*display: flex;*/
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container > div {
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px;
  flex: 0 0 calc(100% - 20px);
  text-align: left;
}

/*img {
    padding-left: 7%;
    max-height:55px;
    width:auto;
}*/
td{
  padding: 2px 2px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 6px 0;
  border: none;
}
table{
  width: 100%;
  background-color:#454545;
  font-weight:500;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing:0.3em 1.1em;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
}
tr{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-transform:capitalize;
}
tr:nth-child(1) {
    color: #CCC;
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
 
#one,#two,#three,#four{
    padding-top:2%;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h4 style="color:#000;">Result table (dynamic).</h4>
<div id="two"></div>

<h4 style="color:#000;">Table that I want to get (static)</h4>
<div><table> <thead> <tr> <th>plat</th> <th>chan</th> <th>cat</th> <th>num</th> </tr></thead> <tbody> <tr> <td>plat1</td><td>chan1</td><td>cat1</td><td>555</td></tr><tr> <td>plat1</td><td>chan1</td><td>cat2</td><td>850</td></tr></tbody></table></div>
```

Comment: Instead of hiding some table columns using a function at the end of the script, where do you think I should manipulate the data in order to make the script more efficient? I do not know how to change this part: result.push(value);. But I am thinking the best way is to change the script in the getCells function.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: At the moment we get all the columns from the JSON. Let's say I want to hide column Chan. I can use a hide function and hide it at the end of the script. I just wonder whether this could be done in the getCells function.

Comment: I am using this script for now: ` var table1 = '';
 // Clean the table. Keep the needed columns
 for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) { 
  platformJSON = JSON.stringify(result[i][0]);
  rateJSON = JSON.stringify(data.rows[i][4]);
  objJSON = JSON.stringify(data.rows[i][2]);
 }
 
 for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) 
 {
  if(platformJSON.match(/plat1/))
  {
   table1 +="<tr><td>" + result[i][0] + "</td><td>" + result[i][1] + "</td><td>" + result[i][3] + "</td></tr>";
  }
 }`

Comment: If you want to change the visibility of columns i would go for a CSS solution instead of rerendering the table.

Comment: I might have different versions of tables depending on some column values. My code above fails as if the regex is wrong. I removed the regex and filtered for a specific value but it does not seem to work so far. I will try to work on that now.

Comment: The IF statement fails: `for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) 
{
    platformJSON = JSON.stringify(result[i][0]);
    objJSON = JSON.stringify(data.rows[i][2]);
    rateJSON = JSON.stringify(data.rows[i][4]);

    console.log(platformJSON + '_' + objJSON + '_' + rateJSON);
 
    if(platformJSON == 'plat1' && objJSON == 'cat1' && rateJSON == 'group1'){
        table1 +="<tr><td>" + result[i][0] + "</td><td>" + result[i][1] + "</td><td>" + result[i][7].toFixed(2) + "</td><td>"+ result[i][2] + "</td><td>" + "</td></tr>";}
}` 
although the console works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial solution. I hope OP can format transformed data into HTML table. Note that I changed `plat1` to `plat 1` to make sure it works with spaces in values as well.

```js
const data = {
            "headers": ["plat", "chan", "group", "cat", "num"], "rows": [
            ["plat 1", "chan1", "bbb", "cat1", 222],
            ["plat 1", "chan1", "bbb", "cat1", 333],
            ["plat1", "chan1", "bbb", "cat2", 850]]
        };
        //only "groupby" columns
        const headersOfInterest = ['plat', 'chan', 'cat'];//, 'num'];
        //aggregation column here
        const numInd = data.headers.indexOf('num');
        const headInd = [];
        //put indeces of headersOfInterest into a separate array
        headersOfInterest.forEach(txt => { headInd.push(data.headers.indexOf(txt)); });
        //transformed data will go here
        const transform = {};
        for (let i = 0, row; row = data.rows[i]; ++i) {
            let propName = '';
            headInd.forEach(val => { propName += row[val]; });
            if (!transform[propName]) {//this way groupping works
                transform[propName] = [];
                headInd.forEach(val => { transform[propName].push(row[val]); });
                transform[propName].push(0);
            }
            transform[propName][transform[propName].length - 1] += row[numInd];
        }
        console.log(transform);
```

Answer (score 1):

Nice with so many different approaches. Here's one using (lodash)[https://lodash.com]. I added some console.logs because it can be hard to follow what happens when you chain lodash methods. The [whole thing can be viewed here as a **JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/jonahe/zv9xztdn/).

But the only new parts are

```
function printSummationTable(relevantHeaders, headerToSum, dataRows) {
  const tableHeader = createTableHeaders(relevantHeaders);
  const collapsedRows = 
    _(dataRows) // enhance the array, to enable chaining of (lodash) method calls
      .groupBy(comparisonStringForColumns(['plat', 'chan', 'cat'])) // results in an array (actually object.. but ignore that) of row groups (arrays)
      .map(peekWithMessage('After .groupBy'))
      .map(rowGroup => {
        // if we know we won't have to support more columns in the future
        // we can just copy the first of the groups (since the rows in the group are "duplicate")
        // BUT we add the "sum of the group" for the specific num value
        const collapsedRow = {...rowGroup[0]}; // check out "spread operator"
        collapsedRow.num = getSumOfValuesInColumn(headerToSum, rowGroup);
        return collapsedRow;
      })
      .map(peekWithMessage('After "collapse" step'))
      .value();
    // treat sumData as a single table row
  const tableRows = collapsedRows.map(row => createTableRow(relevantHeaders, row));
  let table = `<table>${ tableHeader }<tbody>${ tableRows }</tbody></table>`;
  $("#two").html(table);
}

// given a list of headerNames, give back a FUNCTION that
// takes a row an returns a concatinated string
// of the values corresponding to the headerNames
function comparisonStringForColumns(headerNames) {
    return function(row) {
    // make a string from the the relevant values
    // Used for grouping rows that should be considered the "same".
    let comparisonString = '';
    headerNames.forEach(header => {
      comparisonString += row[header];
    });
    return comparisonString;
  }
}


function peekWithMessage(message) {
    return function logAndPassThrough(x) {
    console.log(message, x);
    return x; // to be able to continue chaining
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems that the fiddle does not work though. I have not QAed why.

Comment: Seems to work for me. I removed the hardcoded table so there are only two tables showing, if thats what you mean. Either way I can not  spend more time on it now, so maybe go with one of the others if this one doesnt work. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the QA. It is an obsession trying to code late at night :P Now everything seems obvious. Haha. For this question, I will accept the first one as it worked. I will inform you if I want to expand my question with more ... curiosity :)

Answer (score 0):

I have updated code for html and javascript. Please try this.
Let me know if this works for you I will add explanations if needed.

```
<h4 style="color:#000;">Table before summing the number for the rows that have the same value in the first three columns</h4>
<div id="one"></div>
<h4 style="color:#000;">Table where we can see the SUM but for all the rows. The first three columns are a concatenation of the values which should not happen.</h4>
<div id="two"></div>
<h4 style="color:#000;">Table that I want to get (static)</h4>
<div>
<table> 
<thead> </thead> 

<tbody> </tbody>

</table></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var data = {"headers":["plat","chan","group","cat","num"],"rows":[["plat1","chan1","bbb","cat1",222],
["plat1","chan1","bbb","cat1",333],
["plat1","chan1","bbb","cat2",850]]};

createHeader();
createBody();
function createHeader(){
  $('thead').append((function(){
  var row = '<tr>';
 data.headers.forEach(function(element, index){
   row +='<th>' +element+'</th>'
}) 
 row += '</tr>'
 return row;
})())
}


function createBody(){
  var test = {};
data.rows.map(function(element, index){
var count = element.pop();
var content = element.join(':')
if(test[content]){
 test[content]= test[content]+count;
}else{
test[content] = count;
}
})
$('tbody').empty().append($.map(test, function(index, element){
  var row = '<tr>'
     element.split(':').map(function(ele, ind){
     row +='<td>'+ele+ '</td>'
   })
    row += '<td>'+index+ '</td></tr>'
    return row;
}))
}

</script>
```